# Extending a class that has been instantiated without 'new'

Tags: php, class, oop, extend

I am using a library from Github that I am adding to my project via Composer. In my code, I want to extend the library classes. I would normally be able to do this with a simple `extend` and `new` e.g.

```
class myNewClasses extends classesFromTheLibrary
{
// add my custom methods here
}

// instantiate with new
$allClasses = new myNewClasses; // $allClasses can access methods in myNewClasses and classesFromTheLibrary
```

But, this library is instantiated as follows:

```
$document = \Sokil\Vast\Document::create('2.0');
```

So the `new` technique can't be used. Also, some of the classes I would like to extend are in different namespaces, such as `\Sokil\Vast\Ad\Inline`.

*How do I extend classes when the instantiated this way and with different namespaces?*

For reference, the library I'm trying to use is [here](https://github.com/sokil/php-vast)
... and I've tried the decorator technique discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011910/how-to-add-a-method-to-an-existing-class-in-php), but that doesn't seem to work either.

** EDIT **

Perhaps I am barking up the wrong tree here with `extends`: The `::create('2.0')` may be a distraction.

What I am trying to do is add a method to a class in a different namespace to the parent.

The first instantiation happens at the top level: `\Sokil\Vast\Document`, but the class I want to extend is `\Sokil\Vast\Ad\Inline` ... but if I extend that class, I can't instantiate it, because it is instantiated within `\Sokil\Vast\Document` that I don't have access to. Hope that makes sense. Any ideas?

Comment: That looks like it is instantiated via a [static method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php). I'm not sure but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280492/extending-php-static-classes) is relevant.

Comment: Does `myNewClasses::create("2.0")` not work? The author of that class did not intend it to be easily extended (if he had then he would have used the constructor, not a static method). Complain to the author.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, No - because [`create()`](https://github.com/sokil/php-vast/blob/master/src/Sokil/Vast/Document.php#L29) will always return an instance of the superclass without additional changes from the subclass.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen and @HPierce, it seems you are both right: `myNewClasses::create("2.0")` does work (when using `extends \Sokil\Vast\Document`), but the additional classes in myNewClasses don't extend to the different namespaces (such as `\Sokil\Vast\Ad\Inline`).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this would do:

```
class myDocClass extends \Sokil\Vast\Document {
    private $parentObj;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->parentObj = parent::create('2.0');
    }
}

$myDoc = new myDocClass();
```

You can't assign to `$this`, so I've created a property linking to the parent obj, which is instantiated in the `create()` static method of the parent.

Comment: This seems to instantiate the class but then errors further down the code where it uses $this saying that it is null.

Comment: What method did you try to call ? All methods from the parent class aren't in `$this`, but they're in `$this->parentObj` (`$this->parentObj->method()` for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Since version 0.6 added ability to override element classes, so any custom element or element's attribute may be added.

First let's create class for `MediaFile` and add some custom attribute:

```php
<?php

namespace Acme\Vast\ElementBuilder\Element;

use Sokil\Vast\Creative\InLine\Linear\MediaFile;

class AcmeMediaFile extends MediaFile
{
    public function setMinDiration($seconds)
    {
        $seconds = (int)$seconds;
        if ($seconds <= 0) {
            thow new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid min duration specified, must be positive int')
        }

        $this->domElement->setAttribute('minDuration', $seconds);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now we need to override default element builder and create own `MediaFile` factory method:

```php
<?php

namespace Acme\Vast\ElementBuilder;

use Sokil\Vast\ElementBuilder;
use Acme\Vast\ElementBuilder\Element\AcmeMediaFile;

class AcmeElementBuilder extends ElementBuilder
{
    /**
     * <Ad><InLine><Creatives><Creative><Linear><MediaFile>
     *
     * @param \DOMElement $mediaFileDomElement
     *
     * @return AcmeMediaFile
     */
    public function createInLineAdLinearCreativeMediaFile(\DOMElement $mediaFileDomElement)
    {
        return new AcmeMediaFile($mediaFileDomElement);
    }
}
```

Now we need to confugure VAST factory to use overridden element builder:

```php
<?php

use Acme\Vast\ElementBuilder\AcmeElementBuilder;
use Sokil\Vast\Factory;

$elementBuilder = new AcmeElementBuilder();
$factory = new Factory($elementBuilder);

$document = $factory->create('4.1');

$ad = $document->createInLineAdSection();
$creative = $ad->createLinearCreative();
$mediaFile = $creative->createMediaFile();

$mediaFile->setMinDiration(10);
```

See https://github.com/sokil/php-vast#custom-specification-support for more details.