# Get class name of child class in its parent within static context?

Tags: php, inheritance, static-methods

Consider the following parent class `Parent.php`:

```
class Parent {

    protected static $className;

    public static function __static() {
        static::$className = get_called_class();
    }

    public static function doSomething1() { ... }
    public static function doSomething2() { ... }
    public static function doSomething3() { ... }
}
Parent::__static();
```

and its child class `Child.php`:

```
class Child extends Parent { }
```

Each method `doSomething` 1-3 needs to access `$className`. If `Child` calls `doSomething1()`, the `$className` must be `Child`, and **not** `Model`. I could certainly do

```
public static function doSomething() { $className = get_called_class(); }
```

in every method but this would result in code repetition. Plus, `$className` makes most sense to be declared static. The workaround I used is to call a [static class initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312806/static-class-initializer-in-php#3312881) after class declaration in `Parent`. Obviously this didn't work either, because the variable `$class` is still initilized on `Parent`, not on `Child`, *despite* the use of `static` (i.e. late binding).

Long story short, **how do I get the following**:

```
Child::doSomething1(); // -> $className must be 'Child'
Child::doSomething2(); // -> $className must be 'Child'
Child::doSomething3(); // -> $className must be 'Child'
```

Let me complicate it a little bit: I have *multiple* child classes, `Child1`, `Child2`, `Child3`, so placing `ChildX::__static();` at the end of file in each `ChildX` class would be inefficient.

*BONUS*: if I call `doSomething1()` in `Child1`, does that mean that `Child2` and `Child3` will share a static property `$className` with the value `Child1`? My guess is no, but I'd love to hear your viewpoint.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280492/extending-php-static-classes

Comment: @i-- It would be a bit inefficient to redeclare `get_class_name` in every single child... What if I have 10 of them? In fact, in my project, the child is a model, and the parent is a model base class